# Rotation does not trigger when script is executed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a projectile rotate to the target when it spawns in, but it is not currently working, no rotation occurs. Thanks in advance!

Edit: formatting (I hope)

```
 GameObject proj = Instantiate(projectile, projectileSpawns[i].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(projectileSpawns[i].transform.forward)) as GameObject;
                
                proj.GetComponent<BaseProjectile>().FireProjectile(projectileSpawns[i], m_target, damage, fireRate);
                
                Quaternion targetDirection = Quaternion.LookRotation(m_target.transform.position - proj.transform.position);
                
                float singleStep = 100 * Time.deltaTime; 
                
                Vector3 direct = targetDirection * Vector3.forward;

                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, direct, Color.red, 0f, true);
                Debug.Break();

                Quaternion newDirection = Quaternion.RotateTowards(proj.transform.rotation, targetDirection, singleStep);

                proj.transform.rotation = newDirection;
               
                m_lastProjectiles.Add(proj);
```

Comment: No rotation occurs? So if you remove `proj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);` the observed behavior does not change?

Comment: That is correct Ruzihm.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using Vector3 for rotation, use Quaternions.

```cs
...
Quaternion targetDirection = Quaternion.lookRotation(m_target.transform.position - proj.transform.position);
...
Quaternion newDirection = Quaternion.RotateTowards(proj.transform.rotation, targetDirection, singleStep, 0.0f);
...
proj.transform.rotation = newDirection;
```

but that aside, I'm not sure why it's not working. what does the debug ray say about the target? is it working ok in that frame? you can pause game in that frame by `Debug.Break();`

- please make sure your code is formatted well when pasting it here. it was very hard to read like this. --> better formating = better response ( yes. believe me)

Comment: I had to make a few changes in the code so that I could use Quaternions and the debug ray, but the ray seems to point to the target. The projectile still won't rotate. I apologize for the poor formatting, this is my first time uploading to Stack Overflow.

Comment: if it's not rotating, then some other part of your code is having issues. for these times, try debugging it visually, like set the rotation to just Up and see if it's rotating to Up or not. gradually find out which part of the code smells. 
+ saw the downvote? told you about the question formatting. unfortunately, this is Stackoverflow today :(   ( I upvoted just to make it 0 )